# get field value on its change in django models

Tags: django, django-admin

I hope you are fine.
I have two fields with the name of price and discountedPrice in a model.
The thing that I want is to get the values of these two fields on their change to calculate the discount percent from them before the admin clicks on the save button.
I will thank anyone to give me a piece of guidance about this matter.

Comment: seems like an API endpoint taking both values and return the discount, and if it's good can be saved

Comment: Yes I excatly mean that. Is it possible to help me to do this please?